# Why is my Cassandra node stuck joining the ring?

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra node which is joining an existing cluster. It begins to bootstrap itself, streams a bunch of data (monitored via `nodetool netstats`), and then seems to finish - but it doesn't actually join the ring. What's the deal? How do I figure out what's going on? There are no errors in the logs at all, it's been plenty of time, and the Cassandra process is doing very little.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, I turned on alllll the debug logging in `/etc/cassandra/log4j-server.properties`, and sifted through the reams of output until I noticed a couple of statements about `OutboundTCP: attempting to connect to *host*` that were appearing for certain hosts but not others. Further investigation revealed that there was limited connectivity between certain nodes in the cluster, due to a networking configuration which was my own fault: the new node could connect to only 3 out of the 5 other hosts in the cluster.

After fixing this, the node was able to transfer additional data, and I was free to pursue a life of religious fulfillment.[*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080339/quotes) *(Also, I ran `nodetool repair` all over the place out of paranoia.)*